# Assign sorted dictionary to the new dictionary

Tags: swift, swift3

I would like to sort dictionary and save it into the same one, but there is type conflict :

Cannot assign value of type [(Int) : (Double)] to the type [Int : Double].

```
dictionary = dictionary.sorted(by: { (elem1: (key: Int, value: Double), elem2: (key: Int, value: Double)) -> Bool in
                        if elem1.value < elem2.value {
                            return true
                        } else {
                            return false
                        }
                    })
```

I know that after sorting it wont be any more a dictionary.

```
let sorted = dictionary.sorted(by: { (elem1: (key: Int, value: Double), elem2: (key: Int, value: Double)) -> Bool in
                        if elem1.value < elem2.value {
                            return true
                        } else {
                            return false
                        }
                    })
```

I've made a simple for loop to loop thought sortet "dictionary" to assign values once more to the dictionary but it does not copy them as a sorted ;/

```
var test = [Int : Double]()

                    for (key, value) in sorted {
                        test[key] = value
                    }
```

How could I assign the sorted dictionary back to the dictionary in the orded I've sorted it ?

**EDID**

For each annotation I have to get a deistance from dropped pin. I've made a dictionary which a `key` is annotation ID and `value` is a distance between annotation and dropped point. I need a dictionary to recognize in view for cell - table view data source; which annotation match which distance. So I have a dictionary with `[Int : Double]` and in table view data source :

```
let annotation = mapAnnotations[indexPath.row]
var distance = dictionary[annotation.ID]
```

Reasuming, shell I sort `mapAnnotations` which is an array of `Object` via `values` inside dictionary with distances which are makred by annotationId ?

It would be sorting array of object.ID by keys from `sorted`

Thanks in advance!

Comment: A dictionary is an *unordered* collection of key/value pairs, you cannot "sort" it.

Comment: @MartinR I kinda need that dictionary which a key is ID - does not need to be sorted, but values have to be.

Comment: Please update your question with a clear description of what you really need.

Comment: Edited. @MartinR

Comment: Don't fight the framework. For example use an array and a custom struct.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I've solved my problem.

First :

Had to sort values in dictionary by using :

```
 let sorted = dictionary.sorted(by: { (elem1: (key: Int, value: Double), elem2: (key: Int, value: Double)) -> Bool in
                        if elem1.value < elem2.value {
                            return true
                        } else {
                            return false
                        }
                    })
```

Then after that I've created an array which is going to have sorted annotations via `sorted` keys.

```
                    for (key, _) in sorted {
                        for ann in mapAnnotations {
                            if ann.ID == key {
                                sortedArray.append(ann)
                            }
                        }
                    }
```

Answer (score 1):

A dictionary itself cannot be sorted the concept is meaningless because they are by their very nature unordered.  When using a dictionary you access the values by their hashable key so order is irrelevant.  Although you can access the keys and values as properties they are also not sorted.

What the sorted method does is allows you to get a sorted array of the dictionary and it returns an array of tupples of the keys and values sorted as you determine.  In the example it would return [(key: Int, value: Double)].  So you can't assign that back to the original dictionary because it's not a dictionary it's an array.

The extra code that then assigns back to the dictionary removes all the sorting you have done because as I stated the concept of sorting a dictionary is meaningless.

Comment: Yep that's what I was getting at.  You don't sort the dictionary you create a sorted array from the dictionary and then use that to build the final annotation array (although I didn't know about the annotation array requirement until the question edit).